# How to get dynamic path from json?

Tags: javascript, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to create a test where I am checking whether all required elements are present in the page. I have json file named json.data which right noe looks like this:

```
    {
    "perfTest": {
        "input":"abc",
        "outputs":["a","b","c"],
        "elemAndXpath": ["Login","password","submit"]
        }
    }
}
```

My test is this:

```
    it("should check that required elements are present", function() {
        var elemNames = data.perfTest.elemAndXpath);
        elemNames.forEach(function(elemName){
            //search on the page that the specified elem is present
            expect(element(by.xpath("//div[.='" + elemName + "']")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

Now this works if all of them can be found my locators which are similar in path. I need to make this test to be able to pick up the locator path to use from the json file. So, my now my JSON file looks like this:

```
 {
    "perfTest": {
        "input":"abc",
        "outputs":["a","b","c"],
        "elemAndXpath": {
            "Login":"by.id('login')",
            "password":"by.id('pass')",
            "submit":"by.xpath(//button)"
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to write the test for this json file. Problem is due to the dynamic nature of the last key. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are passing a string to element. Try this:

```
var data = {
  "perfTest": {
    "input":"abc",
    "outputs":["a","b","c"],
    "elemAndXpath": {
      "Login":"by.id('login')",
      "password":"by.id('pass')",
      "submit":"by.xpath(//button)"
    }
  }
}

for(key in data.perfTest.elemAndXpath){
  expect(element(eval(data.perfTest.elemAndXpath[key]))).isPresent()).toBe(true)
}
```

Comment: No actually..Test I wrote got all the keys from `elemAndXpath`. Now while I want to iterate through all the keys and get there corresponding value, it part doesn;t work for me.

Comment: Unless you need the keys for something else you can just drop them and put the by.x strings as items in the array then I believe the above will work. Otherwise, do a for loop on the object and do the same.

Comment: Yes, I need the keys as well. I tried the for loop thing..I got all the keys using Object. I used for loop to iterate through keys but could not get their values

Comment: Updated answer with the for in loop.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the key part but how to get the value of the respective key?

Comment: It is in there...data.perfTest.elemAndXpath[key] is the value...key is the key.